What is the difference between TargetFramework net8.0-windows and net8.0?
With .NET we can create projects(.csproj files) that can have TargetFrameWork as  net8.0-windows and net8.0
net8.0-windows
 <PropertyGroup>
 <TargetFramework>net8.0-windows</TargetFramework>
 <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
 <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
 <UseWindowsForms>true</UseWindowsForms>
 <Nullable>enable</Nullable>
 <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
 </PropertyGroup>

net8.0
 <PropertyGroup>
 <TargetFramework>net8.0</TargetFramework>
 <OutputType>Library</OutputType>
 <AppDesignerFolder>Properties</AppDesignerFolder>
 <Platforms>x64</Platforms>
 </PropertyGroup>

What differences does they make to the executables? Does TargetFramework net8.0 will help to create libraries that are platform independent

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/frameworks#net-5-os-specific-tfms
